# PNAS style and non-latin characters in author's name

Tags: fonts, accents, characters

I am using style [PNAStwo](http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/PNASDOCS.PDF) (for a submission to [PNAS](http://www.pnas.org/)).

However, its fonts for authors, affiliations and abstract seem do not contain non-latin characters like [ł](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81) (`\l`) or [ø](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98) (`\o`), and produce some *random* symbols like `"`. (In the main text such letters work perfectly fine, tough.)

Is there a workaround to use ł (which is part of my surname) in `\author{...}`?

Ideally, in a way so my surname is parsed to `Migdał` or, at least, `Migdal`.

Comment: Do you happen to know the encoding of your .tex files? If it is, say, `utf8`, you may need to issue commands such as `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` along with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @Mico There is `\usepackage[T1]`; `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` does not change anything (I've tested it; as there is exactly the same problem with `ł` as with `\l`).

Comment: I downloaded the class, and tried filling the template with `\author{Piotr Migda\l \affil{1}{Somewhere}}`. The result is what's expected. Can you present a small example? Did you change the font settings in the `pnastwof.sty` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\usepackage{OT1enc}` solved the problem.